# Does URLSession.dataTask(with:completionHandler:) always call completionHandler only once?

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondatatask

After I create a new session data task with [`URLSession.dataTask(with:completionHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/1407613-datatask) and start the task by calling its `resume()` method, given that the app doesn't crash while the request is running, is it safe for me to assume that `completionHandler` (passed to `URLSession.dataTask(with:completionHandler:)` above) will always eventually get called only once, even if something weird happens with the network request (like if the connection drops) or with the app (like if it goes into the background)?

Note: I'm not explicitly calling `cancel()` or `suspend()` on the task. Just `resume()`.

I want to know the answer to this question because (from my app's main thread) I'm creating and starting (one after the other) multiple asynchronous network requests and want to know when the last one has finished.

Specifically, I'm working on an app that has a custom class called `Account`. On launch, the app (assuming it finds an account access token stored in `UserDefaults`) creates only one instance of that class and stores it to a global variable (across the entire app) called `account`, which represents the app's currently-logged-in account.

I've added a stored `var` (instance) property to `Account` called `pendingGetFooRequestCount` (for example) and set it to `0` by default. Every time I make a call to `Account.getFoo()` (an instance method), I add `1` to `pendingGetFooRequestCount` (right before calling `resume()`). Inside `completionHandler` (passed to `URLSession.dataTask(with:completionHandler:)` and (to be safe) inside a closure passed to `DispatchQueue.main.async()`, I first subtract `1` from `pendingGetFooRequestCount` and then check if `pendingGetFooRequestCount` is equal to `0`. If so, I know the last get-foo request has finished, and I can call another method to continue the flow.

How's my logic? Will this work as expected? Should I be doing this another way? Also, do I even need to decrement `pendingGetFooRequestCount` on the main thread?

Comment: I would recommend using `OperationQueue` and `Operation` to track and handle multiple concurrent network requests. I would also factor it out into a service instead of having your account deal with it. https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-use-multithreaded-operations-with-operationqueue

Comment: @RezaShirazian, why would you recommend `OperationQueue` & `Operation` over the way described in my question?

Comment: are you saying that you need to make multiple requests in series? in other words, don't start the next one until the previous one is finished?

Comment: @meggar, no, the requests are (from the main thread) created and started (one after the other), but they're executed asynchronously, so I want to know when the last one has finished. Thank you for asking. I've updated my question to make it more clear.

Comment: In that case I think you want to use DispatchGroup.  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchgroup

Comment: @meggar, interesting. I didn't know about `DispatchGroup`. That's cool. Thanks for sharing! :-) But, whether I use a stored property (eg, `pendingGetFooRequestCount`) or a `DispatchGroup` to track when all the network requests complete, I still need to know the answer to this question.

Comment: Can't use DataTask in background app state, only UploadTask and DowloadTask with callbacks in the AppDelegate instead of completion blocks. Then you would need to set up the URLSessionConfiguration for background too.

Comment: @meggar, thank you, but that still doesn't answer my question.

Comment: You don't need that counter, just use DispatchGroup with a wait(timeout..), it returns a DispatchTimeoutResult - .success means all dataTasks executed the completion block. if you're asking if dataTask's response can call the completion block more than once, it can't. The global account variable is probably not the best option, maybe a shared account would be an improvement `class Account{ static let shared = Account() }`.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel. There is already a proven, well-document and well-tested library provided by Foundation that handles what you want to do. Unless there was something overwhelmingly different or extra in your case, I'd recommend `OperationQueue`, `Operation`.

Comment: @meggar, thank you. That's a good idea, but I'm just going to assume the answer to my question is yes—If I'm wrong, please let me know—and just use a counter, as described in my question. Because, using a counter seems simpler to me. Also, I don't see why the global variable isn't good. It seems simpler to me than your suggestion.

Comment: @RezaShirazian, thank you, but `URLSession` already has an `OperationQueue` (`delegateQueue`). I don't see how it'd help to create another one.

Answer (score 1):

URLRequest has a timeoutInterval property, its default value is 60 seconds. If there is no response by then, the completion is called with non-nil error.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah, that's what I thought, but that doesn't completely answer my question.